# How can I sort my ListView by Z-A alphabetical instead of A-Z?

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview, android-actionbar, listadapter

The code below is what I use to order my ListView by alphabetical order:

```
 case R.id.menu_order_name:
    adapter.sort(new Comparator<Shop>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Shop arg0, Shop arg1) {
            return arg0.getName().compareTo(arg1.getName());
        }
    });
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
```

When I click it once it sorts by A-Z, although when I click the ActionBar menu option again to sort, I would like it to sort by Z-A.  Can anybody show me how to reverse the order of the sort?

Thanks in advance, all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can try to return -arg0.getName().compareTo(arg1.getName());

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much buddy. You're a life saver! I'll post my completed answer for anybody who is interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of [`String.compareTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29):

> **Returns** 
>   0 if the strings are equal, a negative integer if this string is before the specified string, or a positive integer if this string is after the specified string.

In other words: the short answer is to invert the values currently returned by your `Comparator`. The quickest way to do that would be to simply multiply by `-1`, because:

```
-1 * -1 =  1
 0 * -1 =  0
 1 * -1 = -1
```

That will effectively reverse the sorting order with respect to the original `Comparator`. In code:

```
adapter.sort(new Comparator<Shop>() {
    @Override public int compare(Shop arg0, Shop arg1) {
        return -arg0.getName().compareTo(arg1.getName());
    }
});
```

However, since this is a quite common use case, we can do it even easier by leveraging functionality Java provides. Lets say the original `Comparator` is denoted by `aToZComparator`; we can reverse it using the `Collections` utilities:

```
adapter.sort(Collections.reverseOrder(aToZComparator);
```

This will basically apply the same concept of inverting the comparison result, and effectively change your `aToZComparator` to a `zToAComparator`.

I'll leave it up to yourself to figure out the logic of when to choose which `Comparator`.